# Ionic - using radio buttons in popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

### Controller

```
.controller('FoodCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.favorite = { 'food': 'egg' };

    $scope.setFavoriteFood = function() {
        var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
            'templateUrl': 'popup-favorite.html',
            'title': 'Favorite Food',
            'subTitle': 'Please pick your favorite food',
            'scope': $scope,
            'buttons': [
                {
                    'text': '',
                    'type': 'button-assertive icon ion-close-round'
                },
                {
                    'text': '',
                    'type': 'button-balanced icon ion-checkmark-round',
                    'onTap': function(event) {
                        console.log($scope.favorite.food);
                        return $scope.favorite.food;
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        popup.then(function(result) {
            console.log('your favorite food is ' + result);
        });
    };
}
```

### Popup template

```
<script id="popup-favorite.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-model="favorite.food" ng-value="egg">Egg</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="favorite.food" ng-value="tomato">Tomato</ion-radio>
    </ion-list>
</script>
```

Now, the data binding between `$scope.favorite.food` and radio buttons does not work at all. It is weird that it works again if I replace my radio buttons with a single input field `<input type="text" ng-model="favorite.food">`.

How can I make my radio buttons work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a string inside the quotes

```
  <ion-radio ng-model="favorite.food" ng-value="'egg'">Egg</ion-radio>
   <ion-radio ng-model="favorite.food" ng-value="'tomato'">Tomato</ion-radio>
```

Taken from the example from :http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRadio/

I believe without the quotes it would be expecting to bing to $scope.egg and $scope.tomato.

You could try adjusting your code to use a more dynamic approach like in the example given on the angular docs and having your radio buttons generate dynamically like : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 1):

if you are using $parent in ng-model.Problem is fixed

```
<script id="popup-favorite.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-list>
           <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.favorite.food" ng-value="'egg'" ng-change="test(formData)" >egg</ion-radio>
           <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.favorite.food" ng-value="'tomato'" ng-change="test(formData)">tomato</ion-radio>
        </ion-list>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single input, all you're doing is changing the value of `food`. In the case of radio buttons, you want multiple options so you need to extend your existing object. You could try something like this:

JS

```
 $scope.favourites = [
    { food: "egg", value: 1 },
    { food: "tomato", value: 2 },
    { food: "cheese", value: 3} ]
```

HTML

```
<script id="popup-favorite.html" type="text/ng-template">
     <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in favorites"
                ng-value="item.value"
                ng-model="favourites.food"
                ng-change="doSomething(item)">
                {{item.food}}
     </ion-radio>
</script>
```

If you want to share `food` data between views/controllers, you really should be using a service (if you aren't already).